# Database error - reindex

Tags: error, database, reindex, index

I have an error in the database.

The problem occured in the index, Catalog search index, and I can't reindex data.
I deleted all files in `/var/locks` and tried to do it manually with the command `php shell/indexer.php --reindexall` but I only get an error message for the above mentioned index.

Now I try to use the db repair tool.

I tried to setup a test environment but I cannot make a database dump.

When I try to make a database dump I get following error message:

> mysqldump: Got error: 145: Table './dbname/catalogsearch_fulltext' is
>   marked as crashed and should be repaired when using LOCK TABLES

So, what do i do now?

Comment: truncate and optimize that table, then reindex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357270/php-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired

You might be able to repair the table using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound great! You could try installing a fresh instance of Magento using the same version as your website and then exporting the 'catalogsearch_fulltext' table from there, drop the table from your current Magento instance database and then import the table from the fresh instance of Magento. This should repair the table for you and enable you to reindex again.

You should backup your database before making any changes just in case something goes wrong. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: But I can not make a backup, in admin via php it doesn't work and I can't as mentioned above do a database dump, any other suggestions?